# How to get ImageStream from MediaCapture?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

In WP 8 I used `PhotoCamera` to make a camera app and to save the image in camera roll I used this method:

```
private void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "photo.jpg";
    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
    library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);
}
```

In  WPSL 8.1 I use `MediaCapture` and I use the same style to save image in camera roll but I don't know how to retrieve `ImageStream` from `MediaCapture` like in `e.ImageStream`. I am open to suggestions even with other programming style for saving to camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(IMAGECAPTURE_FILENAME, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await _exceptionHandler.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(_imageEncodingProperties, file);
            var photoStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(photoStream);
        });
```

The above is taken from a UWP app to save an image to storage, then read it from disk as a stream. I've never been able to capture the image directly as a stream.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But how can I save them in camera roll, like whats app for example, not to create my own file

Comment: Aah, yeah, get special folder from UWP, you can see in my example, the file that I am creating is saved in Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary, which is the pictures folder. from there, you should not have a big problem finding the camera roll, which is a subfolder.

Comment: I will try your code and I will let you know. Thanks in advice @Pedro!

Comment: Good luck - don't forget to initialize your MediaCapture. I did it like so: 

            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

            _imageEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

Comment: can you look over my app? [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=861467A1111C7105!7235&authkey=!AIbXe5pqhB9IrrY&ithint=file%2crar)  The photo saved is not good. Can you tell me where is the problem?